# Angular current date and time, time is mismatching with Java LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, angular8, utc, timezone-offset

In my Angular (8) application and Backend is in Java and Spring with mysql db.
for one `http post request` there is date(with time) is a field of the payload.where it will hold the current date and time.

Angular:

```
export class User{
     nowAction: Date;
```

And setting date as

```
user.nowAction= new Date();
```

if I log this time, in browser I am getting this, and it is correct time

***Sun Mar 29 2020 *00:23:11 GMT+0530* (India Standard Time)***

Now in Java

```
private LocalDateTime nowAction;
```

and the date it getting  is 
**2020-03-28 *18:53:11*.764000**

here Data are matching, but there is a difference in Time.
also I a sending utc offset value (ex: +0530)
please let me know how, how I can convert the angular date and tie to actual date and time on java.

Comment: It looks like Java is giving you a UTC date/time instead of the local date time.

Comment: have you tried to use ZonedDateTime instead of LocalDateTime

Comment: @Powerlord Well spotted. If the times have been quoted accurately for the same request, there’s something more going on. 23:28 at offset +05:30 would be 17:58 UTC, not 17:45.

Comment: @Ole V.V. 16 I have updated the question, to edit both the dates of same request.

Comment: Thank you. Your edit confirms @Powerlord’s idea: the time you are getting into Java has been converted to UTC. Isn’t that just fine? You can always convert to something else in Java if you want.

Comment: @Ahmet OZKESEK, this ZonedDateTime  working now I am java date same as Angular date. But issue is the page can be access from any time zone/country and and backend java will host only one fixed timezone, that time it will again mistmatch.

Comment: @Ole V.V. understand java is converrting to UTC, but I want the time with time zone same as page.also I am passing utc offset value(ex: +0530) value to java. need to findout way how to convert the java date to that specfic utc zone.

Comment: Not that I know, but the suggestion of @AhmetOZKESEK to use either `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` in Java sound good and viable to me.

Comment: nope both are not working, as java is hosted in different zone, and the page accessing in different zone.